Azure DevOps Server 2022 - what .NET version? Framework? Core?
Azure DevOps Server 2022  - what .NET version?  Framework?  Core?
I just have a simple one: which .NET Framework version is Azure DevOps server using?
Is this still .net framework 4.?  Or is Azure DevOps Server written in .NET Core?
Maybe Azure DevOps Server is .NET 5 or higher?
And yes this answer may be different for different components I would imagine....

Do you mean that which .NET frameworks are available when you try to call the .NET client libraries of Azure DevOps Server 2022 in your .NET app?

Our information security department has asked our team to remove the out of support NET Core 3.1 and 5 from our webservers, including our Azure DevOps Server.  I wanted to know if that would impact Azure DevOps Server performance at all.

As clarified in my answer below, the frameworks .NET 6,  .NET 7 and .NET 8 also are  compatible in .NET client libraries of Azure DevOps Server 2022. If some of your projects are using .NET 5 or lower, you can upgrade them to be higher, or remove them if no longer require. @user5855178

Based on the information shared in my answer below, is it okay for you to use the latest version of .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Server 2022. @user5855178

If you want to call the .NET client libraries of Azure DevOps Server 2022 (ADO 2022) in your .NET app, it is unnecessary to know which .NET frameworks are used to develop ADO 2022. Actually, there is no official documentation to state this.
The versions of .NET client libraries available for ADO 2022 are 16.205.x and later. The current latest stable version is 19.225.1 (See the NuGet packages gallery).
The main target .NET frameworks compatible or included in the libraries are below:

.NET Framework: net461, net462, net463, net47, net471, net472, net48, net481
.NET Standard: netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1
.NET Core: netcoreapp2.0, netcoreapp2.1, netcoreapp2.2, netcoreapp3.0, netcoreapp3.1
.NET: net5.0, net6.0, net7.0, net8.0

So, your app with any of these .NET frameworks should be able to call the .NET client libraries available for ADO 2022.


